# Align a custom block button by wrapping it in div

Tags: block-editor

I made my custom block button. I want wrap it in  and align a button horizontally. How could you wrap it? Below code has two problems

1. It doesn't allow to edit a text in a button
2. It doesn't allow a button to align center

```js
(function (element, blocks, blockEditor) {
  var el = element.createElement;
  var RichText = blockEditor.RichText;
  blocks.registerBlockType(
    'custome-namespace/button',
    {
      title: 'nice button',
      icon: 'button',
      category: 'layout',
      example: {},
      attributes: {
        text: {
          type: 'string',
          default: '',
          source: 'html',
          selector: 'button'
        },
        align: {
          type: 'string',
          default: 'center',
        }
      },
      supports: {
        align: true,
        justifyContent: true,
        alignItems: true
      },
      edit: function (props) {
        var blockProps = blockEditor.useBlockProps();
        var buttonBlock = el(
          RichText, Object.assign(blockProps, {
            onChange: function handleChange(text) {
              props.setAttributes({ text: text })
            },
            value: props.attributes.text,
            placeholder: 'Input button label',
            tagName: 'button',
            className: props.className,
          })
        );
        return el('div', blockProps, buttonBlock)
      },
      save: function (props) {
        var blockProps = blockEditor.useBlockProps.save();
        var buttonBlock = el(
          RichText.Content,
          Object.assign(blockProps, {
            value: props.attributes.text,
            tagName: 'button',
          })
        );
        return el('div', blockProps, buttonBlock)
      },
    }
  );

})(window.wp.element, window.wp.blocks, window.wp.blockEditor)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry if my previous comment sounded silly... I actually thought nothing major was changed in your code (I didn't check thoroughly on your code).. anyway, let me know if my answer helped?

Comment: Yeah! it fixed like a charm! Thank you so much. Next time I'll write in JSX :)

Comment: Glad it helped, but sorry! You could actually use the `blockProps` with `RichText`.. but nonetheless, see my revised anwer for more details :)

Comment: Thank you so much! You made many things clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turned on [script debugging or the `SCRIPT_DEBUG` constant in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#script-debug), then you would've noticed that your block type causes React to throw this warning: "*Warning: React does not recognize the `tagName` prop on a DOM element.*", so when developing block types, you should enable script debugging — at least, you'll know your code causes a warning or an error, even if the message didn't make sense.. i.e. it doesn't tell something like, "hey, remove `tagName` from your `blockProps` object!".. :)

So as for the problems in question, or the above warning, it's because the [block (wrapper) props](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#block-wrapper-props), i.e. your `blockProps` variable, contained an invalid property/attribute (which is `tagName`) for the `<div>` tag that your `edit()` and `save()` functions return.

That property is added to the `blockProps` when you do `Object.assign(blockProps, { your props })` which modifies the original `blockProps` object — `Object.assign()` works like `array_merge()` in PHP, but PHP doesn't modify the first array passed to the function and simply returns a new array; `Object.assign()`, on the other hand, modifies the first object. So you should have used `Object.assign({}, blockProps, { your props })` instead (note the `{}`), i.e. [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#merging_objects_with_same_properties) the existing `blockProps` object instead of modifying it, e.g. in `edit()`:

```js
var buttonBlock = el(
//  RichText, Object.assign(blockProps, {   // bad
// and it's bad because it adds the tagName property to the blockProps.

  RichText, Object.assign({}, blockProps, { // good
    ... your props.
  })
);
return el('div', blockProps, buttonBlock)
```

However, despite using the `blockProps` (or `useBlockProps`) on other elements would *not* result in any error/warning, I don't think it's needed above, hence I'd use the `blockProps` only on the `div` element. :)